# Select from table where some WHERE condition missing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, conditional-statements

I have following sql request

```
        if(isset($_GET['room'])) {

            if($_GET['status'] == 'all' && $_GET['room'] == 'all'){
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT flatnetto FROM flat ORDER BY flatnetto");
                $stmt->execute(array($_GET['room'], $_GET['status']));
            }else if($_GET['status'] == 'all'){
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT flatnetto FROM flat WHERE kk = ? ORDER BY flatnetto");
                $stmt->execute(array($_GET['room']));
            }else if($_GET['room'] == 'all'){
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT flatnetto FROM flat WHERE sold = ? ORDER BY flatnetto");
                $stmt->execute(array($_GET['status']));
            }else{
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT flatnetto FROM flat WHERE kk = ? AND sold = ? ORDER BY flatnetto");
                $stmt->execute(array($_GET['room'], $_GET['status']));
            }               

            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
```

It is possible to make just one sql request from code above? I mean, it is possible to make  just one request

```
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT flatnetto FROM flat WHERE kk = ? AND sold = ? ORDER BY flatnetto");
```

but condition "kk" and "sold" may or may not exist (will have unsortable "all" value). So for example if "kk" not exist just ignore it and continue selecting only with condition "sold".

Code above is working but it is pretty annoying to define all possible options.

---

Status can have values (Sold, Reserved, All)

Room can have values (1kk, 2kk, 3kk, All)

Value "all" means that for example I am interesting on 2kk room and no matter if is "sold" or "reserved" just show me all of them.

UPDATED Question.

As is wrote on answer below it is possible to make one sql request. But the problem persist because we just move "possible option definition" to sql query but I still have to define all possible option. I can not imagine how to define all possible options if we will have not just two input but for example "room, status ,price1, price2, floor, size ..." and all of them can have own value but also value "all". In this case we have to define all possible options from all possible variations (in this case more than 20 possible variations). I think this is not way how it work in bigger projects.

Comment: no, as long as you have variable to define, there should be binding for that parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to generate your SQL query

```
$param=Array();

## associate query parameters to sql column
$keys=Array("room" => "kk", "status" => "sold");

## generate parameter list
foreach ($keys as $k=>$v)
if (isset($_GET[$k])&&($_GET[$k]!='all'))
   $param[$v]=$_GET[$k];

## generate query
$query="SELECT DISTINCT flatnetto FROM flat WHERE ".
    implode(" = ? AND ", array_keys($param)).
    (count($param) ? " = ?" : "1")
    ." ORDER BY flatnetto";

## execute
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($param);
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to be much usable piece of code. I will test it and let you know.

Comment: definitely working, I just have to change $stmt->execute($param); to $stmt->execute(array_values($param));

Answer (score 0):

Consider a union query exhaustive on the All possibilities. Depending on choice parameters, only one line of query will output:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT flatnetto FROM flat WHERE kk = :kk 
AND sold = :sold AND NOT kk = 'all' AND NOT sold = 'all ORDER BY flatnetto
UNION SELECT DISTINCT flatnetto FROM flat WHERE kk = 'all' AND sold = :sold
ORDER BY flatnetto
UNION SELECT DISTINCT flatnetto FROM flat WHERE kk = :kk AND sold = 'all'
ORDER BY flatnetto
UNION SELECT DISTINCT flatnetto FROM flat WHERE kk = 'all' AND sold = 'all' 
ORDER BY flatnetto");
$stmt->execute(array(':kk' => $_GET['room'], ':sold' => $_GET['status']));
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems that it is possible to make one sql raquest. But please  chceck updated question.